# A man is born in 1955

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation, time

(I heard this in a movie and I think it’s pretty cool.)

A man is born in 1955. Today, the 14th of August, 2017, he is 18. How is this possible?

Comment: "Today" is 1973?

Comment: No, "Today", is the 14th of August. Sorry for the confusion, I changed the post to prevent any further confusion.

Comment: Perhaps 18 is his age listed in Base 54. :P

Comment: A man rode into town on Wednesday, stayed for two nights, and left on Tuesday. How is this possible? :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister He has a horse named Wednesday

Comment: @JimJones this riddle reminded me of it. Very similar nature.

Comment: @Michael There are only 10 people in the world, those who know binary and those who don't. You, my friend, are the latter.

Comment: That would make him 111110.

Comment: For a slightly less imagined (and easier) example: My mother died in 1988. Since then, she has had seven death anniversaries.

Comment: The real riddle is how his mother managed to birth a man. Most of us only just barely manage babies.

Comment: @Fogmeister - or he left on a horse named Tuesday

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is simply:

> 1955 is *where* he was born. So either hospital room number or home address if home birth!

I have heard this one before but I don't remember where, maybe the movie you mentioned.

Comment: After answering I looked it up and its a pretty easy google find too!

Comment: Yeah, but regardless still a nice riddle.

Comment: True maybe a good one to annoy ppl with on the fly!

Comment: The puzzle might have worked better with ['33 instead of '55](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treinta_y_Tres) ;-)

Comment: There similar puzzles involving twins, with one born in March and one born in e.g. September. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March,_Cambridgeshire (The most complicated version being with them born either side of midnight on a month boundary, as the ambulance crosses the town boundary.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Love your name! This could have also worked with '84 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighty_Four,_Pennsylvania)

Comment: Apperently, people are keeping a list of places like these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_with_numeric_names

Comment: another option (for example): if "today he is 7" ... then, his name could be 'Seven' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven (...or any other number that serves as a name, e.g., a girl named Octavia (she is 8), ...

Comment: Joan Rivers made a joke like this once.

Answer (score 24):

> He was born on an extrasolar planet that revolves around its star in 3.4444444444444 Earth years.

Comment: Good thought, sir. I like the way you think.

Answer (score 13):

> "Today, he is 18." Which means his name is 18. Or he is in jail, having number 18.

Answer (score 10):

> The man died in 1973 and thus only lived 18 years?

Comment: But then would you say he's 18 _today_? (This question already has an accepted answer, btw.)

Comment: the accepted answer is lame...i like this better

Comment: You're right, the accepted answer is lame. Who needs that ruddy answer. Be creative! There's more than one answer.

Comment: This is what I thought first xD

Answer (score 10):

At the risk of giving the obvious answer(s),

> - He’s been in suspended animation / stasis for 44 years.
>
> or, almost equivalently,
>
> - He’s been travelling in space for $n+44$ years
>    at such (relativistic) high speed
>   that only $n$ years have passed *for him* during his trip,
>   so he’s aged only $n$ years. 
>   (And he’s spent only $18-n$ years on Earth.)

Comment: The second one is why I make fun of trying to handle absolutely every case in medical software.

Comment: This is a very possible possibility.

Answer (score 3):

> The person was in space or another planet. People age differently in space/other planets.

Answer (score -2):

> This man acted in **interstellar** movie maybe.